# can't using Start-Process powershell.exe run a ps1 file at onedrive path

Tags: powershell, onedrive

I have a ps1 file in Onedrive for Business path. when running below command, it gets something wrong, but it runs so fast, I can't get the error screenshots.
If I put the script in another local drive path, it works fine. 
Any prevention in Onedrive?

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList $ps1path
```

ps file content

```
$current_path = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$up1_path = Split-Path -Parent $current_path
$up2_path = Split-Path -Parent $up1_path
$up1_path
$up2_path

cmd /c "pause"
```

Comment: When you run your command in powershell, does the powershell window close after execution? what runs so fast ?

Comment: I don't know which script it runs. I have put a pause at the end of script .

Comment: I have tried Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy bypass , but still can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not Onedrive case. Just the start-process can't accept a space in ArgumentList.

```
$pspath = $pspath -replace ' ','` '
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList $pspath
```